# how to handle browser pop up(you might lose the data, are you sure you want to continue?', with two options: Leave the page Stay on page)

Tags: java, selenium, popup, webdriver

My scenario

1. i am working on page 1
2. i have to switch to page 2
3. but the pop up is coming, with text
   `you might lose the data, are you sure you want to continue?`, 
   with two options:

   - Leave the page
   - Stay on page
4. i have to choose "leave the page" option
5. but how to handle this pop up, 
   (note :-i) this is not an alert, so switch to alert is not working 
   ii) even `(( JavascriptExecutor ) webDriver).executeScript( "window.close()" );` is not working )
   then only i can switch to page 2
   can someone please help on this

Comment: Have you tried with sending keystrokes (Tab + Enter) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although It doesn't  seems as an alert because `alert.accept()` or `alert.dismiss()` doesn't works.(as you haven't shared `html`) Just try the following code -

First switch on that alert -

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

and then change focus to  `leave` if your default focus is on `Stay`

```
alert.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.TAB)); //By pressing TAB key in this way
```

and then click the button

```
alert.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work:

```
//Save the current window to switch back to it after clicking on Leave Page
String currentWindowHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();

//Switch to the latest window (a.k.a your pop up)
for(String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles())
{
    driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}

//Click on leave page

//If the window closes automatically, you can remove the below line
driver.close();
//Finally, switch back to the main window so you can keep doing stuff there.
driver.switchTo().window(currentWindowHandle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, it's a browser alert which you are receiving so you can use following code based on your requirement :

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();

    System.out.println(alert.getText());
```

If you want to stay on the page, use:

```
alert.dismiss();
```

If you want to leave the page, use:

```
alert.accept();
```